# Nested loops and to keep the index count going in the second one

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got two nested loops and I'm trying to increment a counter in the second one, so basically that the count does not reset.

now: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
want: 1 2 3 4 5 7 8

In vanila javascript I would have a variable but how is it done in Vue land?

**EDIt**
I want the count in the template not the javascript part.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    todos: [],
    activeIndex: -1
  }),
  mounted() {
    for (let t of ['first', 'second']) {
      const listObjects = []

      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        listObjects.push({
          url: `/${t}/${t}-${i}`,
          name: `${t}-${i}`,
          type: t
        })
      }

      this.todos.push({
        type: t,
        listItems: listObjects
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="todo of todos">
    <ul>
     <li 
     v-for="(item, i) of todo.listItems" 
     :class="{ 'item--is-active': activeIndex === i }">
     {{ item.name }}
     </li>
    </ul>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Set ‘i’ to 0 before you start the first for loop and remove the ‘i = 0’ in the second for loop.

Comment: @SudoKid I'm looking for how to do it in the template not the script part

Comment: which counter in the template are you talking about?

Comment: @Prashant The second counter to keep incrementing instead of reset `(item, i)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    todos: [],
    activeIndex: -1,
    counter: 0,
  }),
  mounted() {
    for (let t of ['first', 'second']) {
      const listObjects = []

      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        listObjects.push({
          url: `/${t}/${t}-${i}`,
          name: `${t}-${i}`,
          id: ++this.counter,
          type: t
        })
      }

      this.todos.push({
        type: t,
        listItems: listObjects
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="todo of todos">
    <ul>
     <li 
     v-for="(item, i) of todo.listItems" 
     :class="{ 'item--is-active': activeIndex === i }">
     {{ item.name }} id: {{ item.id }}
     </li>
    </ul>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Vue but I think you need something like:

```
mounted() {
  let i = 0;
  for (let t of ['first', 'second']) {
    const listObjects = []

    for (; i < 10; i++) {
      listObjects.push({
        url: `/${t}/${t}-${i}`,
        name: `${t}-${i}`,
        type: t
      })
    }

    this.todos.push({
      type: t,
      listItems: listObjects
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and don't take it the wrong way. If you read my question I specifically mention I need it to be in the template, this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Define a variable outside of both loops and increment it inside the second.

If you want tthe variable to be reactive, declare the variable on the data object

```
data () {
  return {
    loopCounter: 0,
    todos: []
  }
}
```

Notice that I declared data as a method returning an object. This way all the instances of a component have their own data object and not share one. In your case, a vue instance, is not a problem, but in general you should declare it as a method and not an object.

Edit:

You could save the info on each listItem and print it from there instead of computing it on the spot.

You could use a data for loop count that you increment it inside the loop

```
{{loopCounter++}}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the data return but I got that part, I just took the template from jsfiddle. But how do I increment it though?

Comment: I updated my question with the exact scenario that it should be. So this solution won't work.

Comment: You could use this activeIndex === loopCounter ++ or you could use a combined index between the first loop and the second one instead of the numeric activeIndex.

Comment: have you tried it? I can't get it to work they way you describe. The counter will start a t 4001

Comment: This is similar to what I thought would work but the counter starts at 4000 (why?) and also more importantly:
Error: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function